# What is the point of reference / origin for coordinates obtained from a stereo-set up? (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, robotics, stereo-3d

I set up a stereo-vision system to triangulate 3D point given two 2D points from 2 views (corresponding to the same point.) I have some questions on the interpretability of the results.

So the size of my calibration squares are '25mm' a side, and after triangulating and normalizing the homogeneous coordinates (dividing the array of points by the fourth coordinate), I multiply all of them by 25mm and divide by 10 (to get in cm) to get the actual distance from the camera set up.

For eg - the final coordinates that I got were something like `([-13.29, -5.94, 68.41])` So how do I interpret this? `68.41` is the distance in the `z` direction, and `-5.94` is the position in the y and `-13.29` is the position in the x. But what is the origin here? By convention is it the left camera? Or is it the center of the epipolar baseline? I am using OpenCV for reference.

Comment: I think this has to be defined by the camera system. Could be anything.

Comment: Correct, I guess what I meant was - what is the default in OpenCV? I couldn't find it in the docs

Comment: guess: depends on the order of matching (right to left or left to right). If you can visualize the depth map, maybe you see some "correlation" with either left or right camera. This would be my experiments to find out the origin.